# W3C module does not exist

Tags: java

I try to do Y! Weather XML parsing for the sake of learning using BlueJ. When I compiled the class, BlueJ giving me error: `package org.w3c does not exist`

Here is the code:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.io.InputStream;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import org.w3c.*;

public class WeatherApp
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        URL xmlURL = new URL("http://weather.yahooapis.com/forecastrss?w=22722924&u=c");
        InputStream xml = xmlURL.openStream();
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(xml);
        xml.close();

        System.out.println(doc);
    }
}
```

What could go possibly wrong here? And how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: "What could go possibly wrong here?" Well, the compiler is telling you. The package `org.w3c` does not exist. Or can't be found.

Comment: Ah I should add "how to fix this problem" too. I wonder why it can't be found.